# How can i create a dynamic dictionary in a Python script sharing its contents with another script?

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have a Python dictionary as follows

```
dictvvalue={'a':'1','b':'2','c':{'d':'5','e':'6'}}
```

My intention is to save this Python dictionary for use by another Python script.

I have to load this dictionary to the other script as a dictionary rather than as a string.

Please help

Thank you

Comment: Use the [`pickle`/`cPickle` module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/pickle.html).

Comment: Or [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).

Comment: Or you can try this recipe for a [persistent dictionary](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576642/) (referred to in the [docs](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576642/) for the `shelve` module). This may be overkill depending on the complexity of your needs.

Answer (score 1):

As Generic alluded to, you *must* encode it as a bytestring before you can persist it, and then decode it when reading in. The common ways to do this in Python are pickling (via `pickle`/`cPickle`), JSON (via `json`), or YAML (via PyYAML).